# Serializer SimpleXML just send first line

Tags: java, android, xml, servlets, outputstream

I have a problem trying to send a file xml between Android and a servlet with POST. I'm using  ([Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net)) for the serializing.

My servlet do the response to Android:

```
Serializer serial = new Persister();
OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();

MyXML myXML = new MyXML();
myXML.setMyElement("test");
serial.write(myXML, o);
```

It's supposed to send my xml directly to the client like this,

```
<MyXML>
  <MyElement>test</MyElement>
</MyXML>
```

But it only sends the first line . Then, on the Android side gets this exception because it can't get the second line with the Element.

```
WARN/System.err(490): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'MyElement' does not have a match in class java.lang.Class at line -1
```

I can't understand why it only serialize the first line when i'm doing it with OutputStream because it works when i'm saving on files without sending it,

```
Serializer serial = new Persister();
File file = new File("MyPath");

MyXML myXML = new MyXML();
myXML.setMyElement("test");
serial.write(myXML, file);
```

I need to do it like that and not with bytes, just to avoid to set the response content length.

Many thanks,

**EDIT**: Adding MyXML.class

There is MyXML.class,

```
package part.myApp;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name="MyXML")
public class MyXML{

       @Element(name="MyElement")
       private String a;

       public void setMyElement(String a){
           this.a=a;
       }

       public String getMyElement() {
          return a;           
       }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post what the class MyXML looks like complete with the Simple XML Framework annotations? I can help if I have more info.

Comment: I've edited my post with MyXML.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private access on 'a' might be a problem. [Use the POJO options](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#javabean):

```
@Root(name="MyXML")
public class MyXML{
       private String a;

       @Element(name="MyElement")
       public void setMyElement(String a){
           this.a=a;
       }

       @Element(name="MyElement")
       public String getMyElement() {
          return a;           
       }
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Still not working. I don't know why servlet reponse just send back first tag <MyXML>. I've tested the data received on client side and it's just the tag, nothing else. I'm using Simple 2.4.1 because I'm working with Android and there is a bug in 2.5 version.

Comment: I am using the 2.5.3 version myself on one of my projects. What is wrong with the 2.5 version? And are you still getting the same error message?

Comment: I'me getting exactly the same error. If I use 2.5 version I get another error: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1287): java.lang.VerifyError: org.simpleframework.xml.core.StructureBuilder.

Comment: I've used in a part of my project where I'm working without Android and I'm getting same error with 2.5.3 version.